# Change Width and Font of TextField in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, textfield, midp, lcdui

Firstly I want to emphasize that I'm talking about TextField in J2ME (javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField) not TextField in AWT (java.awt.TextField).

Could you tell me if this is possible in J2ME? I want to change the font (font family, font size, font color) of the TextField, I also want to change the width it is rendered on the form. I tried using setMaxSize() but this also limits the number of characters the TextField can contain. What I want is changing the TextField's width without limiting that number of characters.

If these couldn't be done, I don't think programmers can make their J2ME application look best. Or at least they would have another control which supports these features.

Comment: Not being able to change the looks of high level UI elements makes sure that all LCDUI apps looks the same on the same device. It is up to the manufacturer to decide how the high level elements should look like. So if you don't like how it looks, blame the manufacturer.
But many others before you weren't happy with this, so lots of LCDUI alternatives have been made, and LWUIT has become one of the most popular ones. You want LWUIT.

Comment: Maybe, I have no other choice, I have thought of some control for this but not TextField in LCDUI. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change width and font of TextField in Java ME, [API Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#setInitialInputMode%28java.lang.String%29) for this class have nothing related to font (actually, the very word font isn't mentioned in these docs).

> If these couldn't be done, I don't think programmers can make their J2ME application look best.

You are right but the reason for this limitation is that TextField and other high level UI API are intended to allow programmers write simple highly portable code (leaving details on what font to use on large/small screen to the system).

This is pretty well explained in [lcdui package API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html), in section **Structure of the MIDP UI API**:

> The high-level API is designed for business applications whose client parts run on MIDs. For these applications, portability across devices is important. To achieve this portability, the high-level API employs a high level of abstraction and provides very little control over look and feel. This abstraction is further manifested in the following ways:
>
> - The actual drawing to the MID's display is performed by the implementation. Applications do not define the visual appearance (e.g., shape, color, font, etc.) of the components.
> - Navigation, scrolling, and other primitive interaction is encapsulated by the implementation, and the application is not aware of these interactions.
> - Applications cannot access concrete input devices like specific individual keys.
>
> In other words, when using the high-level API, it is assumed that the underlying implementation will do the necessary adaptation to the device's hardware and native UI style...

Regarding fonts, of high level UI API classes [Choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Choice.html) implementations such as `List` and `ChoiceGroup` have some capabilities, but these are pretty limited, consult with API docs for details if you are interested.

---

For fuller access to features you look for, study the "low level" part of the API, described in the package docs referred to above:

> This API is designed for applications that need precise placement and control of graphic elements, as well as access to low-level input events. Some applications also need to access special, device-specific features... Applications that program to the low-level API are not guaranteed to be portable, since the low-level API provides the means to access details that are specific to a particular device...

In particular, [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html) class has methods to get and set font - called respectively, `getFont` and `setFont`.

Note by the way that features provided by Graphics could be "embedded" within Form using [CustomItem API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is very clear. I have another question, if I use a low-level API, how can I know which devices it supports? (I guess LWUIT is a low-level one, isn't it?).

Comment: @KingKing low level API is supported on same devices as high level one - you would just have to write code to make sure that stuff you draw matches device screen size (high level API does that for you, at the expense of being less flexible). As fo [tag:lwuit], it's a 3rd party library, UI toolkit. For your purposes it looks worth considering. If you're interested in details, check [lwuit tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lwuit/info) and questions in this tag

Comment: When you say "low level API is supported on the same devices as high level one" do you mean that my J2ME application will run OK on MIDP supported devices no matter what API (low level or high level) I use but if the device's capability is limited, using low level API will make my J2ME application look different to what I see when designing ? What about this line quoted from your answer "...since the low-level API provides the means to access details that are specific to a particular device...". As I understand, it shows that less MIDP devices support low-level API than high-level API.Thanks!

Comment: @KingKing oh that's simple. Easy example of device specific details is screen width. High level UI API would cover it for you but with low level, it will be your responsibility to write code that takes it into account. Say, if you wrap your text at 300 pix and it will look bad at 200 pix wide screen, it will be your fault, your bug. Or, if you wrap text at 60 pix and it will look ugly at 200 pix wide screen, it will be your fault, again. Other than that, if (note: **if**) you write correct code, it will work right at any device that supports [tag:midp] API, high and low level UI all inclusive

Comment: Thank you gnat, you deserve my acceptance for your answer, although Venkat's answer is also helpful to me. I wish I could accept all your answers as I can do in CodeProject. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to customize the components like TextField in J2ME, I strongly suggest you to use [LWUIT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html)(Light Weight User Interface Toolkit) for it. You can create good UI through LWUIT for java mobiles and customize them as you wish. As name tells, it is really light wight.

Simple Code to Customize TextField in LWUIT is as follows :

```
TextField myTextField = new TextField();
myTextField.getStyle().setPadding(9,9,9,9); // Top , Left , Bottom , Right padding
myTextField.getStyle().setMargin(7,7,7,7);  // Top , Left , Bottom , Right padding
myTextField.getStyle().setFont(*use the font whatever you wish*);
```

Note : Please see about the .RES file and Resource Editor which is every help for the change the look and feel of the application. You can import the fonts into .RES file and use it in your code.

Comment: @KingKing If it is helps you , accept it as an answer by clicking the Tick symbol and upvote it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can accept only 1 answer :( I hope you agree with my decision, let's look at gnat's effort, he was trying to explain to me many important things, not simply a workaround. I've really appreciated that. I also up-voted both of you. Thanks...